# Fixed-Dynamic block in AndEngine

Tags: box2d, andengine, collision

I am trying to create something like this: http://s14.postimage.org/8i013r9a9/movable.png

If I create BoxBody with BodyType.DynamicBody, it bounces from other object and fly away but I can move UP-DOWN (setVelocity),
if I create BoxBody with BodyType.StaticBody, it remains on place, but I can't get it to move.

http://s15.postimage.org/pfvvlbpor/movable2.png - and that block must move UP/DOWN

How can I create movable obstacle??

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use joints in the Box2D extension, see the manual:
http://www.box2d.org/manual.html
You are probably looking for prismatic joint.

Also look at kinematic bodies, I think you can move them like dynamic bodies but they will not respond to collisions with other bodies so they may fit your needs.

Comment: Please explain what you meant by using square. Yes, kinematic bodies only collide with dynamic bodies, so you cannot constrain their movement with static bodies such as walls. You will need to change their position yourself, for example set the obstacle's linear velocity, then keep checking whether it has reached the turning point and then reversing the velocity so that it moves back, and repeat. There may be a better way of doing this that I am unaware of, maybe someone else will provide a better solution.

Comment: look at the second image, is it still not clear what I need? I want that objects bounce from that block, but it NOT bounce from objects, but continue to move up and down... not left, right or somewhere else

Comment: I understood that from the very beginning, but I still don't know what the first comment means. :-) Maybe you misunderstood how the joints work? Anyway, I think you can create a prismatic joint connecting the floor and the obstacle. This will restrict the movement of the obstacle to certain direction and length, it will act as a sort of a piston. Behold my mad mspaint skills ;) http://i49.tinypic.com/2wbs66o.png

Comment: "Maybe you misunderstood how the joints work?" - yes :)) , now I understood... Thank you very much. I will try in the evening.